# Using a custom font on a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, userscripts

I am currently working on a userscript that adds features via buttons for Cookie Clicker. I nearly have it finished but i would like the game font to be used as the button font but I have no idea how to do this, I know it is possible as I saw it about two years ago but I can't remember where. The font that i want used is "font-family:\"Kavoon\""

The part of the script that is relevant is as follows:

```
function addStyleSheet() {
    var stylesClassName = options.panelId + '-styles';
    var styles = document.getElementsByClassName(stylesClassName);
    if (styles.length <= 0) {
        styles = document.createElement('style');
        styles.type = 'text/css';
        styles.className += ' ' + stylesClassName;
        styles.font = superFont
        document.body.appendChild(styles);
    }
    var css = '#' + options.panelId + '{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;background:#000;color:#fff;padding:5px;z-index:9999;}#' + options.panelId + ' button{margin-left: 5px;}#' + options.panelId + ' button.active:after{content:"*";color:red;}';
    styles[(typeof document.body.style.WebkitAppearance == "string") ? "innerText" : "innerHTML"] = css;
}
```

and here is an example of how one of the buttons are set out like:

```
var options = {
    panelId: 'cookie-cheater',
    intervalDelay: 1,
    buttons: {
        'bigCookie': {
            label: 'Autoclick Big Cookie',
            action: function () {
                toggleAutoAction('bigCookie', function () {
                    Game.ClickCookie();
                })
            }
        }
```

I would be very appreciative if someone could come up with some ideas or a solution!

Thanks,
Daniel

.....................................................................................................................................................................

EDIT: DONE! pulled an allnighter to get this done and I'm finished, I learnt a lot and ended up with my own solution, please, if you are in the same situation as I was, use the updated method that Brock Adams posted on Ravi Hamsa's post.

Thanks to all of you for your help!
Daniel

Comment: See @Ravi Hamsa's updated answer, below.  Also, accept answers and comment on answers as appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line into your head tag.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavoon' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

this will make "Kavoon" ready to use in your page, then you can use `font-family:Kavoon` in your style.

---

**Update:**
To add the `<link>` **in a userscript environment**, use this code:

```
var D           = document;
var linkNode    = D.createElement ('link');
linkNode.type   = "text/css";
linkNode.rel    = "stylesheet";
linkNode.href   = "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavoon";

var targ = D.getElementsByTagName ('head')[0] || D.body || D.documentElement;
targ.appendChild (linkNode);
```

Then Activate the style with code like this:

```
GM_addStyle ("button {margin-left: 5px; font-family: 'Kavoon', cursive;}");
```

In fact, you should be using [`GM_addStyle()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle), which is supported by all major userscript engines, not that `addStyleSheet()` function.

Comment: Thanks, this would have really helped, and will help for others in this situation, but I finished before I saw this sorry. I will EDIT my post to tell them to use this method as I don't particularly like my method, t is a bit messy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In order to use your font, you must include the web font. A quick Google search yielded your exact font (good news): http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Kavoon

First, place this in your `<head>` element. This tells the browser to download the font to the local machine to use it on your web page.

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavoon' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Then, select your element, and add the font family to it.

```
.my-btn {
  font-family: 'Kavoon', cursive;
}
```